# Python module not found when importing existing one

Tags: python

I'm getting module not found error despite having `__init_.py` files where required.
My structure is the same as in other sample project where `test_...` files work as expected.

Error that I'm getting appears in `test_cicd_in_aws_stack.py`

When doing `from cdk_code.cicd_in_aws_stack import CicdInAwsStack`, I'm ending with

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cdk_code'`

```
.
├── README.md
├── app.py
├── cdk.json
├── cdk_code
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── cicd_in_aws_stack.py <---importing CicdInAwsStack class from here
│   ├── lambda_stack.py
│   └── stage.py
├── requirements-dev.txt
├── requirements.txt
├── source.bat
└── tests
    ├── __init__.py
    └── unit
        ├── __init__.py
        └── test_cicd_in_aws_stack.py <---importing CicdInAwsStack class here
```

Comment: It sounds like you need to run `pip install` to install a [CDK](https://pypi.org/project/cdk/) module. Does requirements.txt or requirements-dev.txt tell you which Python modules you need as pre-requisites?

Comment: CDK installed, `synth` works as expected.

Comment: If this is still a problem, can you open a shell, switch to the relevant directory (much like you would do with the python command) and type `pip list`. The output will show which modules are available.

Comment: `cd` to top level and `pip list` doesn't see `cdk_code.cicd_in_aws_stack`